# Order of invocation of listeners

Tags: netty

Is it guaranteed that the listeners of an instance of io.netty.util.concurrent.Future will be called in the order they were added once the former is completed? If yes, is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is ... If it's not mentioned I will add it to the docs.